# How can I Replace invalid characters 0x1E in data returning from DB

Tags: c#

I get some invalid date from DB - an invalid characters 0x1E, how can I replace it with this -  "" ?

Comment: Is it string? How about var newString = string.Replace("0x1E", String.Empty);

Comment: Is this what you have http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647001/dealing-with-forbidden-characters-in-xml-using-c-sharp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error exists if to try to serialize xml-characters, [here is the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1647001/dealing-with-forbidden-characters-in-xml-using-c-sharp-net).

The most simple solution is to just remove the forbidden characters from the source string:

```
var newString = new string(
    str.Select(c => (int)c)
    .Where(i => i >= 32 || i == 9 || i == 10 || i == 13)
    .Select(i => (char)i)
    .ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(myfield, CHAR(30), '') FROM mytable;
```

That should strip out any 0x1E characters from `myfield`.

Or, to clean the database table, use:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield = REPLACE(myfield, CHAR(30), '')
  WHERE myfield LIKE ('%' + CHAR(30) + '%');
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is very useful , but can you tell how can I replace incorrect values after I read value from DB ?